# Adding a textfield to state as array

Tags: reactjs

im fairly new and this is my first project in react.

Im trying to create a form so that I can submit a dynamic amount of arrays to a firestore document.

So im using an onChange handler for the fields, first field is just a string and works fine, but the second field needs to be converted to an array before its added to the state, iv tried using an if statement to check for commas, and if found to do a split, but as far as I can tell, the split isnt creating an array from my string.

So if I look at the state being displayed its showing me a string still..

What am I doing wrong?

[front-end view showing JSON.stringify results of state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5oPV.jpg)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function NewProduct() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ brand: "", models: [] }]);

  // handle input change from Brand field
  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
  };

  // handle input change from Models field
  const handleArrayChange = (e, index) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    if (value.indexOf(",") > -1) {
      value.split(",");
      console.log("Comma found");
    }
    console.log([value]);
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = [value];
    setInputList(list);
  };

  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputList(list);
  };

  // handle click event of the Add button
  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([...inputList, { brand: "", models: [] }]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="max-w-4xl m-auto">
      <p className="w-full text-lg font-semibold text-center">Passar till:</p>
      <p className="w-full text-sm text-center mb-5">
        Ange en tillverkare och flera modeller, om du behöver fler tillverkare,
        klicka på knappen Lägg till:
      </p>
      {inputList.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <div className="flex flex-wrap">
              <label className="w-4/12">
                <p className="w-4/12">Tillverkare</p>
                <input
                  className="border w-11/12 p-1.5"
                  name="brand"
                  placeholder="T.ex. Electrolux"
                  value={x.tillverkare}
                  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                />
              </label>
              <label className="w-6/12">
                <p className="w-full">
                  Modeller (separera med kommatecken ",")
                </p>
                <input
                  className="border w-full p-1.5"
                  name="models"
                  placeholder="SilentPerformer ESP72DB, Pure C9 Allergy PC91-ALRG, ..."
                  value={x.modeller}
                  onChange={(e) => handleArrayChange(e, i)}
                />
              </label>
              <div className="flex flex-auto items-end justify-end">
                {inputList.length !== 1 && (
                  <button
                    className="text-xs w-18 p-2.5 bg-gray-300"
                    onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}
                  >
                    Radera
                  </button>
                )}
                {inputList.length - 1 === i && (
                  <button
                    className="text-xs w-18 py-2.5 px-2 ml-1 bg-gray-300"
                    onClick={handleAddClick}
                  >
                    Lägg till
                  </button>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>{JSON.stringify(inputList)}</div>
      <div>
        <button className="border p-2 mt-10">SKICKA</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default NewProduct;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing

```
if (value.indexOf(",") > -1) {
  value.split(",");
  console.log("Comma found");
}
```

with:

```
if (value.indexOf(",") > -1) {
  value = value.split(",");
  console.log("Comma found");
}
```

`value` is a string and could not be mutated in place, but instead the result of the `split` method is returned and could be assigned to a value (reassigned to `value` in our case). This will give you an array, so further below you could just do `list[index][name] = value; // value is an array` instead of `list[index][name] = [value];` as well.
Also in the scenario of not having a comma in the string, value will become an array with the string in it, so you don't need to make the explicit check:

```
const handleArrayChange = (e, index) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value.split(",");
    const list = [...inputList];
      
    console.log([value]);
    
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check for commas. Simply, the `split` method will create the array for you and separate elements if there are any commas in the string.

```
const handleArrayChange = (e, index) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value.split(",");
    setInputList(list);
};
```